# Языковая константа в манифесте xml

Tags: xml, joomla

Пытаюсь вывести значение языковой константы в xml, обернув в теги html. Приведённый код не срабатывает. Текст вставляется, только если убрать всё (даже пробелы), кроме самой константы, однако оформления, в таком случае, нет. Подскажите, что не так?

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[<div class='well'><h1>Template</h1>]]>
    TPL_NEWTEMPLATE_XML_DESCRIPTION
    <![CDATA[</div>]]>
</description>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Нужно вставлять html-теги в файл локализации используя одинарные кавычки либо экранируя двойные.

Одинарные:

```
TPL_NEWTEMPLATE_XML_DESCRIPTION="<div class='well'><h1>Template</h1>Description</div>"
```

Двойные:

```
TPL_NEWTEMPLATE_XML_DESCRIPTION="<div class="__QQ__"well"__QQ__"><h1>Template</h1>Description</div>"
```

А в xml вставить просто константу:

```
<description>TPL_NEWTEMPLATE_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
```